# Illegal Service Endpoint error from Dataloader.io

Tags: api, data-loader, etl

I am wondering if anyone uses Dataloader.io which connects to SF instances.  If so have you ever received an "Illegal service endpoint" error?  This would also be a question directed to anyone who has used the APIs before.  I've verified it happens to all of my connections except root connection all of a sudden. It very well could be a DL issue but querying the API ninjas out there for any advice.

Comment: Why in the world would someone downgrade my question especially two years later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try refreshing you Secondary connection in your Dataloader Settings.
Go to Settings->Connections->New Connection->Salesforce.
In the popup authenticate with the credentials of the connection you want to refresh.
After that try to use that Secondary connection again.
:)